# Artifactory not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, artifactory

I don't understand the following error. I have deployed site-plugin:3.3 on the Artifactory but receiving this error message. I don't understand what it means and I'm confused by it. The Artifactory server have access to Maven repo1 through a proxy since I tested the connection to repo.

1. it says it could not find the plugin.
2. it fails to find the plugin at the following location.
3. it says what it could not find was cached in the local repository..
4. it will not reattempt until remote repos has elapsed or updates are forced..

`[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.3 in http://lab.computer.ip:8070/artifactory/remote-repos was cached in the local repository, 
resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of remote-repos has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your local repository got hosed if you killed a build halfway-through or something.  Try removing that directory from your local .m2 folder.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means Maven failed to find the requested plugin (maven-site-plugin:3.3) in Artifactory (remote-repos repoitory) and is caching this failure response. Maven will not try to download the plugin from Artifactory until the update interval for the remote-repos will be elapsed.
Maven has an [updatePolicy](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.2.1/maven-settings/settings.html) which is the frequency for downloading updates - it can be "always", "daily" (default), "interval:XXX" (in minutes) or "never" (only if it doesn't exist locally).

You should first check that this plugin is available through Artifactory. Normally this should be available from one of the remote repositories configured (JCenter, repo1 etc.).
 Since your are resolving from the remote-repos repository, you should try to see if the plugin is available at http://lab.computer.ip:8070/artifactory/remote-repos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.jar. If not, try [tracing](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-TraceArtifactRetrieval) the request using the following: http://lab.computer.ip:8070/artifactory/remote-repos/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.jar?trace.
To force Maven to try and download the plugin again you can either run it with the **-U** option or delete the corresponding failed to download artifact directory in the local reposioty.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://dzone.com/articles/how-resolve-mavens-failure) article saved me

> For Unix Users
>
> 1. find ~/.m2  -name "*.lastUpdated" -exec grep -q "Could not transfer"
>      {} \; -print -exec rm {} \;
> 2. Right click your project and choose Update Dependencies
>
> For Windows
>
> 1. CD (change directory) to .m2\repository
> 2. execute this command for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
> 3. Right click your project and choose Update Dependencies